# How to convert string as stdClass object to array [PHP]

Tags: php, arrays, object

I'm coding a login system using API.
i'm stuck with the result that i got using the API.
I got the result as normal string like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [success] => 1
    [message] => Array
        (
            [code] => 000
            [txt] => Operation successful
        )

    [data] => Array
        (
            [result] => OK
            [accountID] => 000000000
            [group] => demoCAC
            [currency] => USD
            [enable] => 1
            [read_only] => 0
            [name] => Bogus Demo
            [country] => ****
            [city] => 
            [address] => 
            [phone] => **
            [email] => ***@gmail.com
            [status] => test
            [regdate] => 07/02/2017 09:57
            [lastdate] => 07/02/2017 09:57
            [balance] => 0.00
            [credit] => 0.00
            [equity] => 10000.00
            [isDemo] => 1
            [tp_version] => **
            [last_name] => Demo
            [first_name] => Bogus
            [domain] => ***.com
            [compliance] => 
            [latestTrades] => Array
                (
                    [results] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [totalResults] => 0
                )

            [owner] => 
        )
    )
```

So how can i convert it to an array or useable variable ?
* This information printed by ( echo ), 
and i can't access $result -> data ->...
is there a function that convert this string to array or json or something readable so i can reach to specific value?
when i try :
 print_r(get_object_vars($result));
i get this error:

Warning:  get_object_vars() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given in /home/**/public_html/crm/profile.php on line 20

Comment: How did you print that information? If you were using `var_dump` or `print_r` then your result isn't actually a string but already an object, and thus have access to its properties (eg. `$result->success` will be equal to the success value, `1` in this case)

Comment: it seems to be a var_dump display .. you can check eval function http://php.net/manual/fr/function.eval.php to convert string to php code

Comment: Is this the string that your api returns? If it is, you should switch to a format that is easy to parse like json.

Comment: provide us more code

Comment: Also DO NOT USE EVAL!  Fky's suggestion is profoundly dangerous and will only lead to a world of hurt.

Comment: Show us the code you use to fetch and print this API output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless Im missing something, your problem is a simple one.

looking at the guts of your var_dump, you should be able to access the index in your question like:

```
$result->data['email'];  // where 'email' is the key of the data.
```

or

```
$result->data['latestTrades']['results']; // nested example.
```

all the properties of a standard class are public, and so can be accessed directly.  And in your example, all of them contain an array, or nested array so can be accessed by their key.